# 2D A* path finder

Tags: c++, pathfinding

How can I improve the speed of this path finder A* implementation?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct PathFinderNode
{
public:
    short X, Y;
    int H;
    bool IsNull = true;

    PathFinderNode(short x, short y, int h)
        : X(x), Y(y), H(h)
    {
        IsNull = false;
    }

    PathFinderNode *LastNode;
    PathFinderNode *NextNode;
};

struct Point
{
public:
    short X;
    short Y;
};

template <size_t Width, size_t Height>
#define var auto

std::vector<PathFinderNode> FindPath(byte (&matrix)[Width][Height], Point Start, Point End)
{
    int Heuristic = 0;

    std::vector<PathFinderNode> stack;
    stack.push_back(PathFinderNode(Start.X, Start.Y, 0));

    var *closed = new bool[Width + 1, Height + 1];
    PathFinderNode *FinalNode = NULL;

    while ((FinalNode == NULL && stack.size() > 0))
    {
        std::vector<PathFinderNode*> NewStack;

        for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++)
        {
            if (stack[i].H > Heuristic)
            {
                NewStack.push_back(&stack[i]);
                continue;
            }
            if (stack[i].X - 1 <= Height)
            if (stack[i].X - 1 >= 0)
            if (!closed[stack[i].X - 1, stack[i].Y])
            if (matrix[stack[i].X - 1][stack[i].Y] != 0x01) // wall
            {
                PathFinderNode *LastNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);
                PathFinderNode *NewNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X - 1, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);               
                NewNode->NextNode = NULL;
                NewNode->H = LastNode->H + matrix[(byte)stack[i].X - 1][stack[i].Y];

                LastNode->NextNode = NewNode;
                NewNode->LastNode = LastNode;

                if (stack[i].X - 1 == End.X && stack[i].Y == End.Y)
                {
                    FinalNode = NewNode;
                    break;
                }

                closed[stack[i].X - 1, stack[i].Y] = true;
                NewStack.push_back(NewNode);
            }
            if (stack[i].X + 1 <= Height)
            if (stack[i].X + 1 >= 0)
            if (!closed[stack[i].X + 1, stack[i].Y])
            if (matrix[stack[i].X + 1][stack[i].Y] != 0x01)
            {
                PathFinderNode *LastNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);
                PathFinderNode *NewNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X + 1, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);
                NewNode->NextNode = NULL;
                NewNode->H = LastNode->H + matrix[(byte)stack[i].X + 1][stack[i].Y];

                LastNode->NextNode = NewNode;
                NewNode->LastNode = LastNode;

                if (stack[i].X + 1 == End.X && stack[i].Y == End.Y)
                {
                    FinalNode = NewNode;
                    break;
                }

                closed[stack[i].X + 1, stack[i].Y] = true;
                NewStack.push_back(NewNode);
            }
            if (stack[i].Y - 1 <= Width)
            if (stack[i].Y - 1 >= 0)
            if (!closed[stack[i].X, stack[i].Y - 1])
            if (matrix[stack[i].X][stack[i].Y - 1] != 0x01)
            {
                PathFinderNode *LastNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);
                PathFinderNode *NewNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y - 1, stack[i].H);
                NewNode->NextNode = NULL;
                NewNode->H = LastNode->H + matrix[(byte)stack[i].X][stack[i].Y - 1];
                LastNode->NextNode = NewNode;
                NewNode->LastNode = LastNode;

                if (stack[i].X == End.X && stack[i].Y - 1 == End.Y)
                {
                    FinalNode = NewNode;
                    break;
                }
                closed[stack[i].X, stack[i].Y - 1] = true;
                NewStack.push_back(NewNode);
            }
            if (stack[i].Y + 1 <= Width)
            if (stack[i].Y + 1 >= 0)
            if (!closed[stack[i].X, stack[i].Y + 1])
            if (matrix[stack[i].X][stack[i].Y + 1] != 0x01)
            {
                PathFinderNode *LastNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y, stack[i].H);
                PathFinderNode *NewNode = new PathFinderNode(stack[i].X, stack[i].Y + 1, stack[i].H);
                NewNode->NextNode = NULL;
                NewNode->H = LastNode->H + matrix[(byte)stack[i].X][stack[i].Y + 1];
                LastNode->NextNode = NewNode;
                NewNode->LastNode = LastNode;

                if (stack[i].X == End.X && stack[i].Y + 1 == End.Y)
                {
                    FinalNode = NewNode;
                    break;
                }
                closed[stack[i].X, stack[i].Y + 1] = true;
                NewStack.push_back(NewNode);
            }
        }
        Heuristic++;
        stack.clear();
        stack.reserve(NewStack.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < NewStack.size(); i++)
            stack.push_back(*NewStack[i]);
    }

    return stack;
}
```

Comment: Dry is the keyword of the day :-)

Comment: This isn't A*, I don't know what it is but it's not A*

Comment: `#define var auto`? Seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algorithm**

`A*` is a breadth-first search + heuristic algorithm. The loop structure should look something like:

```
while q is not empty:
    next = best path from q
    if next reaches goal:
        return next

    pop q
    for each neighbor of last node:
        add new path to q
```

Your code does not at all resemble that algorithm. I do not know what your `Heuristic` variable is. In the algorithm, the heuristic is a *lower-bound* estimate for the remaining cost. It is a per-path estimate, which for 2D grid we would just use Manhattan distance (or straight-line distance if diagonal steps are allowed - I cannot tell). It is not a algorithm-level variable.

Ultimately, you have a `vector` (named `stack`??) that you are doing something with every element on every iteration. That's really not how the algorithm works.

**Neighbors**

You have four huge blocks of code that all do the same thing, just with different neighbors. Just write a function that given a point returns its neighbors:

```
template <size_t Width, size_t Height>
std::vector<Point> neighbors(byte (&matrix)[Width][Height], Point source);
```

And then you can just iterate over that:

```
for (Point neighbor : neighbors(matrix, {stack[i].X, stack[i].Y}))
{
    if (neighbor not in closed) {
        // do new pathing here with 'neighbor'
    }
}
```

**`PathFinderNode`**

`IsNull` is referenced nowhere - which is good becasue it's always `false` and completely unnecessary. You're making your path a doubly linked list, which is very inefficient. It would be better to simply store it as:

```
struct Path {
    std::vector<Point> points;
    int64_t cost; // or double, if diagonal steps are allowed
                  // or maybe absent, if every step has uniform length we 
                  // can just use points.size()
};
```

**`#define`**

This line:

```
#define var auto
```

should definitely never exist in code. Why? Absolutely not. No no no. No. No no.

**2D Arrays in C++**

This line:

```
var *closed = new bool[Width + 1, Height + 1];
```

outside of using that horrific new keyword you introduced, doesn't do what you think it does. It does not create a 2d array of `bool`s. The comma operator evaluates the first expression, drops the result, and then evaluates the next expression, returning it. If you compiled with warnings on, you would probably get one for this line, as it's exactly equivalent to:

```
bool* closed = new bool[Height + 1];
```

Similarly, this:

```
if (!closed[stack[i].X - 1, stack[i].Y])
```

is really just:

```
if (!closed[stack[i].Y])
```

The correct way to write a 2d array would be:

```
std::array<std::array<bool, Height+1>, Width+1> closed{};
```

**Naming**

```
std::vector<PathFinderNode> stack;
```

That is not a `stack`. UpperCase names for variables are confusing to read and tend to look like class names, so stuff like:

```
NewNode->NextNode = NULL;
```

doesn't look right. Also prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`.

**Checking multiple conditions**

This:

```
if (stack[i].X - 1 <= Height)
if (stack[i].X - 1 >= 0)
if (!closed[stack[i].X - 1, stack[i].Y])
if (matrix[stack[i].X - 1][stack[i].Y] != 0x01) // wall
```

is not going to make you a lot of friends. If you want to check multiple conditions, use the logical and operator:

```
if (stack[i].X - 1 >= 0 && stack[i].X - 1 <= Height &&
    !closed[stack[i].X - 1][stack[i].Y] &&
    matrix[stack[i].X - 1][stack[i].Y] != WALL)
{ ... }
```

Although this should go away completely once you implement `neighbors()`.

Also, don't use magic numbers. `0x01` is confusing. `WALL` is not.

**Does this even work?**

Between the algorithm choice and the not-really-closed set that you have, I'm doubtful that this code works as written. It'd be worth at least going over the [`A*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) wikipedia page and doing some research on search in general.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, My code i posted does in fact work however.
I was originally written in c#, i was simply porting it to c++ and looking for improvements. You've shown me alot of things i've done wrong and i appreciate the feedback.